# Customer site missing wsdl?

Tags: wsdl

I am writing a simple add-on to an existing application for iOS to save files to our customer's Sharepoint file system. When I look at the /_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL it gives me a 404 file not found error.  What can I do to help my customer fix this issue? is there a setting that they need to enable in order to have these WSDL's available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check that the web.config in SharePointRoot\ISAPI contains

```
<system.web>      
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            ...
            <add name="Documentation" />
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    ...
</system.web>
```